# Super simple Make-File echoing does not work

Tags: makefile, echo, output

I have written a very simple Make-File that works perfectly. Just some of my echo-commands just don't work and i Have absolute no clue why that is.

```
LIBNAME=E2E.lib

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall 

AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rvs

SOURCES=E2E_P01.c E2E_P02.c Crc.c E2E.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(LIBNAME) clean

$(LIBNAME): $(OBJECTS) 
$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(OBJECTS) 

.cpp.o:
@echo Compiling ... 
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
@echo done

clean:
@echo Cleaning up all the object files ...
rm *.o 
@echo done 
@sleep 5
```

So the output of a make-process is this:

```
gcc —c —Wall —c —o E2E_P01.o E2E_P01.c
gcc —c —Wall —c —o E2E_P02.o E2E_P02.c
gcc —c —Wall —c —o Crc.o Crc.c
gcc —c —Wall —c —o E2E.o E2E.c
ar rvs E2E.lib E2E_P01.o E2E_P02.o Crc.o E2E.o
r— E2E_P01.o
r— E2E_P02.o
r— Crc.o
r— E2E.o
Cleaning up all the object files ...
rm *.o
done
```

Why are not all echo commands on the output? Obviously there should be a message being printed for every module being compiled (Compiling ... done). Why isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is not being used at all.  Instead, make is using its built-in rules.

That's because your suffix rule `.cpp.o` tells make how to build a `.o` file from a `.cpp` file.  But, the files you want to compile are all `.c` files, so the rule you've defined is useless for that.

Instead, make's built-in rules for building a `.o` from a `.c` are being used and those, of course, don't have your echo commands in them.